# JAX-WS proxies are not thread safe by default. How about the Metro implementation?

Tags: java, thread-safety, jax-ws, cxf, java-metro-framework

According to my research JAX-WS client proxies are not thread safe. As such, the thread safeness of the proxy is left to its implementation. According to [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe?), their proxies are thread-safe. How about the proxies of Metro? Are they thread-safe? I believe Metro is the default JAX-WS implementation bundled in JDK and other Java EE containers. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Just an additional info, according to my research, Metro proxies are not thread-safe. However, I did not found any official documentation to back it up. Also, I tried to test Metro by sharing a single port with 100 threads and I did not encounter any problem. Could it be because I only use 100 threads? Or is it because I did not made any modification on the `BindingProvider`? In the threads, I only use the port to call the web service methods. I did not made any modification on the `BindingProvider`. Is there a specific part only in the Metro port which is not thread-safe?

Comment: Personal experience tells me that Metro is not thread-safe, but I don't think I've ever found a definitive answer to that question in the Metro documentation anywhere.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks for sharing your experience! I've also read somewhere that Metro proxies are not thread-safe but I didn't found an official documentation regarding it on Metro. However, I'm confused because I tried to run a Metro client w/ 100 threads sharing a single port and I did not encounter any problem. Could it be because my threads are only 100? Or is it because I didn't made any modification on the `BindingProvider` in the thread? In the threads, I only use the port to call web service methods and I do not access the `BindingProvider`. Which part of the Metro port is not thread-safe?